# Is there a method for declaring keys of multiple interface as a type?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

My goal is to return the value of the property from the nested object whilst making sure the parameters only pass the key value of the object I'm referring to.

```
    function getResumeInnerProp(data: ResumeList, cat: keyof ResumeList, prop: keyof ResumeInnerProps): keyof ResumeInnerProps {
      const category = data[cat];
      return category[prop];
    }
```

These are the types and interfaces for my objects.

```
//Resume template types
type ResumeType = 'Default' | 'Default2';
type ResumeBgColor = 'navy-blue' | 'maroon' | 'red-orange' | 'blue-green';

//Resume Category Interfaces
interface Personal {
    name: string,
    profession: string,
    phone: number,
    email: string,
    address: string,
    summary: string,
    photo?: string,
}
interface Skill {
    skill: Array<string>,
    category: string,
}
interface Language {
    language: string,
    level: string
}
interface EduExp {
    start: string,
    end: string,
    place: string,
    locality: string,
    description: Array<string>
}
interface Projects {
    date: string,
    project: string,
    description: Array<string>
}
interface ResumeTemplate {
    type: ResumeType,
    bgColor: ResumeBgColor
}
interface Websites {
    github: URL,
    linkedIn: URL,
    personalWeb: URL
}
interface ResumeList {
    personal: Personal,
    skills?: Skill[],
    projects?: Projects[],
    educations?: EduExp[],
    experiences?: EduExp[],
    languages?: Language[],
    websites?: Websites,
    template: ResumeTemplate
}
type ResumeInnerProps = keyof Personal | keyof Skill |  keyof Projects | keyof EduExp | keyof Language | keyof Websites | keyof ResumeTemplate;

//Resume Forms
interface ResumeFormFieldset {
    required: boolean,
    label: string,
    type: [string, string[]] | string,
    id: ResumeInnerProps;
    accept?: string,
    placeholder?: string
}

interface ResumeFormCategory {
    category: string,
    single?: boolean,
    id: keyof ResumeList,
    inputs: Array<ResumeFormFieldset>
}

export { ResumeList, ResumeTemplate, ResumeFormCategory, ResumeInnerProps}
```

Conceptually, I wanted to reference the key types of the following interfaces (which can be seen below) so I can use it as a type for my object id by using "keyof".

I tried both:

```
type ResumeInnerProps = Personal | Skill |  Projects |  EduExp | Language | Websites | ResumeTemplate;
```

and

```
type ResumeInnerProps = keyof Personal | keyof Skill | keyof Projects | keyof EduExp | keyof Language | keyof Websites | keyof ResumeTemplate;
```

but it didn't worked.

This is the code in which the declared type was called.

```
interface ResumeFormFieldset {
    required: boolean,
    label: string,
    type: [string, string[]] | string,
    id: keyof ResumeInnerProps or ResumeInnerProps;
    accept?: string,
    placeholder?: string
}
```

The written code above results in an error that explicitly says:

```
Failed to compile.

src/components/Forms/ResumeFormInfo.vue:145:14
TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
    143 |     function getResumeInnerProp(data: ResumeList, cat: keyof ResumeList, prop: keyof ResumeInnerProps): keyof ResumeInnerProps {
    144 |       const category = data[cat];
  > 145 |       return category[prop];
        |              ^^^^^^^^
    146 |     }
    147 |     return {
    148 |       storeResumeInstance,
```

Additionally, the type displays "never" when hovering the prop parameter from the getResumeInnerProp().

Is there a way to accomplish my goal?

Edit: I managed to properly declare the collection of key types from the selected interfaces due to simple mistakes. However, it still gives the same error from the above.

```
TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Comment: Lots of the types are missing from your question - what is `ResumeList`, what are `Personal`, `Skill`, `Projects` and so on? Please see [mcve].

Comment: `category` could be `undefined` because many of the properties of `ResumeList` are optional. So the error is correct. Is there a reason you think this error should not occur?

Comment: You are right about the optional properties causing the undefined error. Is there a way I can allow multiple optional properties without causing this error?

Comment: You have to deal with the possibility that it's undefined. What do you want your code to do if the property is undefined?